# CursorAdapter vs ResourceCursorAdapter

Tags: android

What is the exact difference between `CursorAdapter` and
`ResourceCursorAdapter`?

Can somebody explain what are the api's that are required to `override`
when implementing my own `ResourceCursorAdapter`?

I have gone through the `ResourceCursorAdapter` documentation and able
to figure out that it's constructor takes an additional layout
parameter as compared to `CursorAdapter` constructor. But I am unable to
understand what is the significance of having an additional layout
parameter in `ResourceCusorAdapter` constructor.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Both [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) and [ResourceCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ResourceCursorAdapter.html) are abstract classes. The exact difference is that ResourceCursorAdapter implements the *newView* method (which is abstract in the base CursorAdapter).

ResourceCursorAdapter also overrides the *newDropDownView* method differently, but that's not the main thing, the main thing is *newView*.

The extra layout in the constructor is what is used to create the view for each item, here is the *newView* method of ResourceCursorAdapter [from the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ResourceCursorAdapter.java):

```
   /**
     * Inflates view(s) from the specified XML file.
     * 
     * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#newView(android.content.Context,
     *      android.database.Cursor, ViewGroup)
     */
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return mInflater.inflate(mLayout, parent, false);
    }
```

Basically, if you don't use ResourceCursorAdapter, you do much the same in your own custom implementation of CursorAdapter. You're free to do more, of course, but if you have a set layout it's easier to extend ResourceCursorAdapter (it adds a bit of convenience, that's all).

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, ctor means constructor. I'll edit to just get rid of ctor.