# Writing custom adapter for listview

Tags: android, listview

Should i extend SimpleCursorAdapter or ResourceCursorAdapter to have a custom adapter for my list view. What is the difference between the two?

The data will be populated from sqlite database. Also i will be using CursorLoader to take care of cursor lifecycle and doing the database activities in a separate thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447413/cursoradapter-vs-resourcecursoradapter

Answer (score 0):

You want to go for `BaseAdapter`

There are tons of tutorials out there, just search custom list view adapter

Comment: Why not ResourceCursorAdapter?

Comment: I found the BaseAdapter super easy to implement. Really its down to you what you go for and the adapters you mentioned may work better or worse. Why don't you test both out and see which works better for your purpose?